# Different views with different code behinds but one binary in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, binaries, windows-10-mobile

I have been reading [this](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2015/04/02/Creating-different-page-views-for-Windows-Apps-based-on-the-device.aspx) which suggests that in windows 10 you can use different xaml views (with the same code behind) for different device families.

My question is whether you can use different views with different code behinds for different device families and still produce one binary.

I know that I can use two head projects with one shared project and achieve the behavior I want but that would produce two binaries.

**EDIT**: To make the question a little bit more specific. Can I add a blank page(for example) **with its code behind**, to the DeviceFamily-Mobile folder and then use it, or must I use only "codebehindless" xaml files in that folder?

Comment: The article is about exactly opposite thing - that you can use single xaml view for different devices (rather than multiple xaml files).

Comment: *My question is whether you can use different views with different code behinds for different device families and still produce one binary.*
Of course this is possible. Name views differently, and based on the device, execute different views.

Comment: @Dusan Later in the article it talks about placing xaml files in DeviceFamily folders. I have edited the question to make it more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried it? If you try it you will answer your own question.

Yes you can **should** still be able to add "regular" xaml pages/user controls to this folder with code behind. You can also have a "shared" code behind file as I described in the blog as well.

Comment: Thanks. That is something that I'm sure to be using when I migrate my app.